# Visual Studio 2015 intellisense adds unnecessary namespace prefixes, then tells me they are unnecessary

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense frequently, but inconsistently, injects namespace prefixes into my code, only to (correctly) tell me they are unnecessary and should be deleted.

This only happens when I press the '(' key while the Intellisense popup is open.  If I press any other key, the class name is injected properly, without the namespace.

I have seen other questions without real answers or with the false assumption that ambiguity is to blame.  There is absolutely no ambiguity in the affected code, so please conserve your time and energy, and do not follow that path.

Example of the problem:

```
namespace One.Two.Three.Something
{
    public class TheVeryUniquelyNamedCollectionClass { }
    public class TheBase { }
    public class TheClass : TheBase
    {
        public TheVeryUniquelyNamedCollectionClass Abcd { get; }

        public TheClass()
        {
            Abcd = new Something.TheVeryUniquelyNamedCollectionClass();   
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above, Visual Studio injects "Something." in the line "Abcd = new Something.TheVeryUniquelyNamedCollectionClass();", then immediately tells me it is unnecessary and should be deleted.

This is happening across multiple projects and solutions, and it is very frustrating having to fight Intellisense.

**Note: Intellisense is now refusing to exhibit this behavior with the '(' key with the example above.  Nothing about the sample code has changed.  It has simply "realized" the namespace is unnecessary and now refuses to inject it no matter what I do.**

**Note 2: I have confirmed that Intellisense eventually figures out the namespace is unnecessary.  I went to another line of code exhibiting this problem, and after retyping it 5 times, Intellisense now behaves properly every single time.  Nothing else changed apart from retyping the line several times.**

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?  This does not sound like something VS does out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Siyual The only extensions not listed as by Microsoft are various Xamarin extensions, PowerShell Tools, Github, and "Command Bus, Event Stream, and AsyncManager MEF".  These were all installed on the same day, so either they were pushed out through a corporate group policy, or they were packaged as part of an update.  The only extension I recall installing is one for Visual Studio Installer projects, to support some legacy setup files, and that was also authored by Microsoft.

Comment: At work we call that system Unitellisense. Among other things it sometimes goes inane because of errors or incomplete or conflicting commits in database. Database is stored near solution and there is no other way to reset it other than delete manually.

Comment: Did you meet this issue recently or it works fine before? Please try to run VS with safe mode using the command: devenv /safemode to check if this installed extension caused it or go to control Panel-Programs and features, right click the Vs 2015, change-repair to repair VS.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT This has been ongoing for at least a year.  Safe mode had no effect.  Change/repair had no effect.  Deleting the .vs folder had no effect.

Comment: @Daniel, did you meet this issue after your initial vs installation? Please go to Tools-Import and Export settings and restore to the default 'General' setting to have a try.